# Header file help & structures

Tags: c, struct, header, malloc

I have a header file, `dimensions.h` and in it:

```
#ifndef DIM_H
#define DIM_H

typedef struct Dimensions
{
    int width;
    int height;
} DIM;

DIM * GetHeader (FILE * fp);

#endif
```

From here I have a c file that does has this:

```
#include "dimensions.h"
.
.
.
DIM *  GetHeader (FILE * fp)
{
    char s[1024];
    struct Dimensions * d = (struct Dimensions *)malloc(sizeof(Dimensions));

    if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", s);
        d->width = atoi(strtok(s, " \n\0"));
        d->height = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n\0"));
    }

    return d;
}
```

But when I run it I get errors like `Dimensions undeclared`. So I played around with the code changing `Dimensions` to `DIM` (still not really understanding the two name 'scheme'.

```
struct DIM * d = (struct DIM *)malloc(sizeof(DIM));
```

Then I get errors with `d->width` and `d->height` saying it's dereferencing pointers to incomplete types, so I swapped `->` with `.` and then an error `request for member width/height in something not a structure or union`.

So not really sure what's going on, might be something really simple that I'm missing so if anyone could help that'd be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1: `Dimensions undeclared`

See this line in your original code?

```
struct Dimensions * d = (struct Dimensions *)malloc(sizeof(Dimensions));
```

If you use `struct Dimensions` somewhere, use it everywhere. Change that `sizeof` to

```
sizeof(struct Dimensions)
```

and the `Dimensions undeclared` should go away.

### Part 2: The `DIM` version

Your code:

```
struct DIM * d = (struct DIM *)malloc(sizeof(DIM));
```

When you `typedef struct {...} DIM`, you need only refer to it as `DIM` - not `struct DIM`.

```
DIM * d = (DIM *)malloc(sizeof(DIM));
```

### Part 3: Swap `->` with `.`

Use `->` when the left side is a pointer to structure, and `.` when the left side is just a structure.

### tl;dr

```
struct Dimensions * d = (struct Dimensions *)malloc(sizeof(struct Dimensions));
```

should fix your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. Just wanted to confirm, the use of the "two names" in the struct `struct Dimensions {..} DIM;` is just so we can reference the struct using `DIM` without `struct`?